# Ruby::test/unit - How do I dynamically insert tests in to the middle of a testcase?

Tags: ruby, module, watir, testunit

I'm a bit new to ruby and test/unit so this may seem like a silly question, but I'm looking for a way to dynamically enter tests in to a template test case (order is important).

Basically I have a testcase that is similar to this:

Master TestCase file:

```
#testcase.rb

require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
require 'watir/testcase'
load "customTest1.rb"

class TC_Test_US < Watir::TestCase
    def test_a
        #do stuff
    end

    def test_b
        #do stuff
    end

    #dynamically load website specific modules here
    include myStuff
    # end of custom tests carry on with generic tests    

    def test_y
       #do stuff
    end

    def test_z
       #do stuff
    end
end
```

--
Custom TestCases

```
#customTest1.rb
module myStuff
    def test_customTest1
       #do stuff
    end

    def test_customTest2
       #do stuff
    end
end
```

Now I have several customTestX.rb files.  Currently I duplicate my test_a to test_z in every file and this sucks when I need to change one or add a new one.

I want to be able to re-use the tests in the master test and just dynamically insert my custom tests in the middle (It's important that test_b stay before my tests and test_y stay after my tests).  I'd dynamically change the "load customTestX.rb" and keep the module named the same in each file.

When I launch this testcase like this I don't get any errors, but none of my custom tests actually execute.   The script skips from test_b to test_y and the customTest1 and customTest2 don't get executed.

The answer probably lies in instancing off of my main testcase.rb, but I haven't been successful in doing this yet.  As soon as you load the master file it executes....   if I remove the testrunner require line I can't load the file without exceptions.  I'm not sure how I would insert my methods in the middle if I did this either.   Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Comment: "order is important" if order of execution is important you have a 'test code smell' that generally indicates tests which are dependent on other tests instead of being atomic.  That often creates lots of maintenance nightmares later down the road, it might be good cause to examine how you are doing things.  Well written functional tests should be able to run in isolation, in any order, or even in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom tests are not running since they do not start with the word "test".

The "test" prefix is how Test::Unit knows which methods are tests vs regular methods. I believe Watir::TestCase is the same.

Try:

```
#customTest1.rb
module myStuff
    def test_customTest1
       #do stuff
    end

    def test_customTest2
       #do stuff
    end
end
```

**UPDATE - Use TestSuite:**

I am not sure why your solution does not work, but one solution that looks like works would be to use a TestSuite. You could then call your starting test cases, your custom test cases and then your ending test cases.

The test suite:

```
#testsuite.rb
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
require 'test/unit/testsuite'
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir/testcase'
require 'testcase_start'
require 'testcase_end'
require 'customTest1'

class TS_MyTests
    def self.suite
        suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new
        suite << TC_Test_US_Start.suite
        suite << MyStuff.suite
        suite << TC_Test_US_End.suite
        return suite
    end
end
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TS_MyTests)
```

Your starting tests:

```
#testcase_start.rb
class TC_Test_US_Start < Watir::TestCase
    def test_a
        #do stuff
       puts 'a'
    end

    def test_b
        #do stuff
       puts 'b'
    end
end
```

Your ending tests:

```
#testcase_end.rb
class TC_Test_US_End < Watir::TestCase
    def test_y
       #do stuff
      puts 'y'
    end

    def test_z
       #do stuff
      puts 'z'
    end

end
```

Your custom middle tests:

```
#customTest1.rb
class MyStuff < Watir::TestCase
    def test_customTest1
      puts '1'
    end

    def test_customTest2
      puts '2'
    end
end
```

Comment: Oops.. In my files they do start with test_.   I just didn't add that here in my example so that doesn't seem to be my problem.  Thanks for the catch though.  Updated original post.